# Coercive operators are invertible

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space and let $A:V \to V^*$ be a bounded linear operator such that
$$\langle Av, v \rangle \geq C|v|_V$$
for all $v \in V$.

Why does this mean that

1. $A$ is an isomorphism
2. $A^{-1}:V^* \to V$ is continuous??
   For 1), one can show that $|Av_1 - Av_2| \geq C|v_1 - v_2|$ so $A$ maps distinct elements to distinct elements, so it must have an inverse.

For 2), I tried 
$$|A^{-1}| = \sup_{f \in V^*} \frac{|A^{-1}f|}{|f|}$$
but can't get anywhere..

Comment: For 1), you proved that $A$ is injective but surjectivity is missing. For 2), take $f\in V^*$ and replace $v=A^{-1}f$ in your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the theorem of Lax-Milgram...